# How can I change the labels of the x-axis of a seaborn violin plot without going back and changing the data?

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

I have the following seaborn violin plot:

```
sns.violinplot( x=c1_census['Cluster Labels'], y=c1_census['Land Area (km2)'],palette=my_pal)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I change the labels of the x-axis without going back and changing the data.
For example:

Replacing
0 for A,
1 for B,
2 for C,
3 for D,
4 for E

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ax.set_xticklabels`:

```
ax = sns.violinplot( x=c1_census['Cluster Labels'], y=c1_census['Land Area (km2)'],palette=my_pal)
ax.set_xticklabels([*'ABCDE'])
```